# Randomized Hoare Partition - Wrong partition on certain indices

Tags: java, algorithm

I literally tried everything, tried every solution but it still won't work. It seems like Hoare partition works only in certain cases but once in a while i don't even understand what it is doing.
Yes, I know how the algorithm works, but implementation wise? I'll be honest, I have no idea how it tries to partition. So, here's my test array:

```
2, 30, 1, 99, 46, 33, 48, 67, 23, 76
```

I first tried to implement the classical algorithm:

```
private int hoarePartition(int l, int r) {
    int pivot = array[l];
    while (true) {
        int i = l - 1, j = r + 1;
        do {
            --j;
        } while (array[j] > pivot);

        do {
            ++i;
        } while (array[i] < pivot);

        if (i < j) {
            int temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = temp;
        } else {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
            return j;
        }
    }
}

private int randomizedPartition(int l, int r) {
    int pivot = generator.nextInt(r - l + 1);

    int temp = array[l];
    array[l] = array[pivot];
    array[pivot] = temp;

    return hoarePartition(l, r);
}

Test cases: [2, 30, 1, 99, 46, 33, 48, 67, 23, 76]

Random Pivot | Partitioned Array                      | Status
0 - [  2 ]     [1, 2, 30, 99, 46, 33, 48, 67, 23, 76]   OK
1 - [ 30 ]     [23, 2, 1, 30, 46, 33, 48, 67, 99, 76]   OK
2 - [  1 ]     [1, 30, 2, 99, 46, 33, 48, 67, 23, 76]   OK
3 - [ 99 ]     [76, 30, 1, 2, 46, 33, 48, 67, 23, 99]   OK
4 - [ 46 ]     [23, 30, 1, 33, 2, 46, 48, 67, 99, 76]   OK
5 - [ 33 ]     [23, 30, 1, 2, 33, 46, 48, 67, 99, 76]   OK
6 - [ 48 ]     [23, 30, 1, 2, 46, 33, 48, 67, 99, 76]   OK
7 - [ 67 ]     [23, 30, 1, 2, 46, 33, 48, 67, 99, 76]   OK
8 - [ 23 ]     [2, 1, 23, 99, 46, 33, 48, 67, 30, 76]   OK
9 - [ 76 ]     [2, 30, 1, 23, 46, 33, 48, 67, 76, 99]   OK
```

The random pivot selection should have been (r - l + 1). With that modification it finally works.

Comment: p is for pivot, r is for what ? How are you choosing the pivot ?

Comment: I modified the code so that it is more readable now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you generate a number that does not have to be in [p,q]:

```
int i = (p + generator.nextInt(q)) % (q - p);
```

The number generated `i` is in range `[0,q-p]`, which is obviously wrong for example in `p=6,q=10`

What you are looking for is:

```
int i = (p + generator.nextInt(q-p+1)); //assuming q>p here
```

This will generate a random number in `[p+0,p+q-p] = [p,q]`

---

As a side note, using `l,r` instead `p,q` will be slightly more readable, and try to be consistent about naming variables (q/r in the two methods have the same role, no reason for two different names)

Comment: (q - p + 1) to be accurate. Please update your answer and I'll accept it because you tossed me to the right direction.

Comment: @Wrath It depends if you want exclusive or inclusive, I assumed exclusive of `q`, but that's also fine.